# Django template concatenate variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates, concatenation

In a loop I want to display fields of my form depending of n items.

```
formCampaign.tags_0
formCampaign.tags_1
formCampaign.tags_2
...
formCampaign.tags_n
```

I want value of each form variables (`formCampaign.tags_0.value`)

```
{% for i in range %}
    <input name="tags_{{i}}" value="{% if formCampaign.tags_???.value %}{{ formCampaign.tags_???.value }}{% endif %}"  type="text">
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you put them in a list in the view, and iterate through that in the template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I can, but my problem will be the same, I have to concatenate a variable name (formCampaign.tags_) with a variable (i), no?

Comment: But that's simple in the view, since you can use `getattr` for example.